# How to copy binary files in Perl program

Tags: perl

I have the below Perl code to make a copy of a binary file that I have.

```
$in = "test_file_binary.exe";
$out = "test_out_binary.exe";
open(IN,$in) || die "error opening ip file: $!" ;
open(OUT,">$out") || die "error opening op file: $!" ;
while(<IN>)
{
 #chomp;
 print OUT $_;
}
close(IN);
close(OUT);
```

But this version of code, the output binary file is of more size than the input binary file size, because this perl code seems to add a 0x0D (Carriage return) character before a 0x0A (newline) character in the input file, it its not already there.

If I use chomp , then it is removed even valid 0x0A characters present, and did not put them in the output file.

1] How can I fix this in the code above.

2] How can I solve this using the File::Copy module, any example code snip would be useful.

thank you.

-AD

Comment: There is no Perl::Copy. Maybe you mean File::Copy? There should be sufficient examples in the documentation.

Comment: @runrig: Yeah, typo. edited it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Always use three-arg `open`.

```
open IN, '<:raw', $in or die "Couldn't open <$in: $!";
open OUT, '>:raw', $out or die "Couldn't open >$out: $!";

my ($len, $data);
while ($len = sysread IN, my $data, 4096) {
    syswrite OUT, $data, $len;
}
defined $len or die "Failed reading IN: $!"
```

However, [`File::Copy`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html) is so easy to use I don't understand why you wouldn't.

```
use File::Copy;

copy($in, $out) or die "Copy failed: $!";
```

Comment: A side note, how does File::Copy module manage to create a file copy with same Time stamps. Thats interesting.

Comment: @goldenmean: It doesn't. At least not under Unix. Look for syscopy in the File::Copy docs. There's /bin/cp -p under Unix.

Answer (score 4):

Call [`binmode`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode.html) on both file handles.

Comment: This is extremely inefficent way to copy files though... Why not use FIle::Copy

Comment: @Cyber-Guard Why not use the `copy` in a cmd shell?

Comment: Sinan Ünür: because writing platform-dependent perl code for no reason is a horrible idea?

Comment: @Wooble: heaven forbid we try and prepare for the unexpected. sheesh.

Comment: zanlok: preparing for the user to use a machine with cmd.exe that doesn't support File::Copy when someone makes such a machine, thus making your code not run on every non-Windows machine out there?  Uh, yeah.